# Unable to create user using postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm having a hard time getting postgres going for the first time.  I installed pg with homebrew and I'm getting a error that looks pretty common on here:

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect            
to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've read that the most common solution is to remove the postmaster.pid file by running `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

However, this results in the following:

```
rm: /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid: Permission denied
```

Any idea how I can get this going?

Comment: What user are you running it as?

Comment: unknown login: postgres

Comment: Is there a postgres entry when you run `ps -ef` equivalent? Can you show how does your pg_hba.conf looks like for local connections?

Comment: @RobinsTharakan I'm not sure how i can find that info.  pretty new to all this.

Comment: Try: "ps -ef | grep postgres" to see if postgresql is running. Then identify yourself as postgres user. As root or with sudo do: "su - postgres" and then use psql. You must be in.